# Question about 2 matrix equations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $A$ is a square matrix and for every $2$ different vectors $X$ and $Y, AX \neq AY,$ then $A$ is invertible.

is it true or false?
thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

$Av$ is non-zero for every non-zero $v$ and so A is invertible.